# XSLT validate and concatenate if parameter is invalid

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some `xsl:parameter`s that I need to validate, and in the detail element I want to concatenate the names of the parameters that are invalid.

I have the checks that validate the parameters but I'm not able to build the detail element. In that element I need to put the invalid parameters separated by ','.

For this input: param1 = 123 and param2 = 50, the detail element should look like this:
`<detail>param1, param2</detail>`

How can I achieve this?

This is the code that I have for the moment:

```
<xsl:template name="validate">
    <invalidParams>
        <jsonArray>
            <xsl:if test="not(fn:matches($param1, '[0-9]{9}'))">
                <xsl:call-template name="invalidParam1" />
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="not(fn:matches($param2, '^(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])$'))">
                <xsl:call-template name="invalidParam2" />
            </xsl:if>
        </jsonArray>
    </invalidParams>
    <detail>
        ???
    </detail>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You can't expect someone to help you if you don't provide an input and an output or at least a detailed explanation.

Comment: I added more details in the post.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid testing the parameters more than once, I would suggest you define a variable along the lines of:

```
<xsl:variable name="params">
    <param name="param1" value="{$param1}" isValid="{matches($param1, '[0-9]{9}')}"/>
    <param name="param2" value="{$param2}" isValid="{matches($param2, '^(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])$')}"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then you can populate the `detail` element using:

```
<detail>
    <xsl:value-of select="$params/param[@isValid='false']/@name" separator=","/>
</detail>
```

and change your template calls to take advantage of the variable too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the error that I get when I define the invalidParams variable:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.xpath.objects.XString cannot be cast to class org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet

Comment: @BocaBogdan, your error message seems to come from Apache Xalan which is an XSLT/XPath 1 processor, it is not clear why you post samples using a function like `matches` which was introduced in XSLT/XPath 2 but try to use an XSLT 1 processor. In the Java world, Saxon 9 or 10 can be used to execute XSLT/XPath 2 or since 2017 even 3.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I'm using WSO2 ESB with enabled support for XPath 2.0 (Saxon Home Edition). I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: @BocaBogdan, org.apache.xpath.objects.XString  is a Xalan class

Comment: @BocaBogdan You can see my suggestion working (using Saxon) here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDkK. As Martin Honnen says, the error you get is coming from Xalan. The code you show in your question cannot possibly work in XSLT 1.0, so you should have seen an error even before trying to implement this.

Comment: Strange, there were no errors with the code from the post. However, in the details section I would like to have the name of the parameters, and not the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:sequence select="
string-join(
 (
   'param1'[$param1[not(matches(., '[0-9]{9}'))]],
   'param2'[$param2[not(matches(., '^(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])$'))]]
 ),
  ', ')"/>
```

============================

**Full code example**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 
 <xsl:param name="param1" select="'123'"/>
 <xsl:param name="param2" select="'50'"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <detail>
     <xsl:sequence select="
        string-join(
         (
           'param1'[$param1[not(matches(., '[0-9]{9}'))]],
           'param2'[$param2[not(matches(., '^(0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9])$'))]]
         ),
          ', ')"/>
     </detail>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied** on any XML document (not used), **the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<detail>param1, param2</detail>
```